# Circuit for another circuit proximity detection

Tags: wireless, proximity-sensor

I just want to ask for some ideas, are there any known low-current circuits to detect direct proximity (max 1-3 cm) of another specially designed device? Must be difficult to "trick" by any other common-world influence, if possible. My goal is to design two PCBs which are only activated by close presence of each other (maybe by some EM/inductive means), both battery-powered.

Comment: What precisely does *max 1-3 cm* really mean?

Comment: Range between 1 and 3 centimeters

Comment: So if they were closer than 1 cm you’d want the system to stop detecting the presence of the other?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that

Edit: nope, sorry, I meant that systems will be activated at small ranges like a couple of centimeters and turned off if pulled apart at longer distance

Answer (score 1):

One idea that immediately jumps to my mind is to use an RFID tag in  one of the devices and an RFID reader in the other. The reader should be able to be keyed to a specific RFID tag. You could also support a set of more than one RFID tag or make categories of types of tags.

Comment: The issue here is that the reader needs to power the tag, and that draws quite a bit of power.

Comment: @jcaron - 99.9% if RFID tag applications the tag does not carry its own power supply. Instead the reader device produces enough energy in the tag antenna to be used as a power supply for the duration of the tag interrogation.

Comment: Yeah, that's what he said as well.

Comment: @MichaelKaras yes, that's what I wrote, but it goes beyond that: to detect the presence of the tag, the reader needs to radiate power continuously (or very frequently): it is actively scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Look for transponders, also known as key fobs from NXP.
https://www.nxp.com/products/security-and-authentication/secure-car-access/tiny-single-chip-passive-keyless-entry-go-solution:NCF29A1MHN

They do not need any power and will be able to work just like normal RFID tags.

Other options are PKE (passive keyless entry) concept used in cars.

As soon as the transponder enters into the range, the transponder will be able to ACK and communicate. The range can be controlled with a 3 D antenna for longer distances (upto 100cms) or design without an dedicated antenna to about a few cms.

Answer (score 0):

If both devices need to be battery powered and you need more than a few hours/days of battery life, you probably need a two-level system:

- A first level needs to detect the presence of the other device using as little power as possible. RFID tag systems or equivalent solutions are not a good idea at this level, as the reader will draw quite a bit of power all the time (or very frequently) just to detect if a tag is present (it would need to actively scan for tags).

  Instead, you could use a [reed switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=Reed+switch) like [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8642) for instance on one device, and a small magnet on the other device.

  A reed switch is normally open, and closes when a magnetic field is present. This is what is used for door sensors (like [this one](https://www.adafruit.com/product/375) for instance).

  This would allow you to have your MCU in sleep mode, drawing very little current, and wake it up when the contact closes.
- Then, to identify you have the "right" other device, you could then use an RFID/NFC reader/tag pair, which would then be activated once presence of the other device is detected.